# How to guess user's timezone using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, timezone, date-fns

I have a requirement, where I need to show a user's time in their local time zone. This needs to be done using date-fns.

The following code checks the current time and then given a timezone converts it into local time as per the time zone.

```
const { formatToTimeZone } = require('date-fns-timezone')

let date = new Date()
const format = 'D.M.YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z (z)'
const output = formatToTimeZone(date, format, { timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta' })
```

However, how do I guess the user's timezone on the fly?

In `moment.js`, you can get it with `moment.tz.guess()`. But how can I do it without `moment.js` and by using `date-fns`?

https://runkit.com/embed/835tsn9a87so

UPDATE: I will be using this inside a VueJS application. So, if there are any other related solutions, those are welcomed as well. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to guess anything. The timezone is automatically supplied by the browser whenever you create a new date object.

Comment: Ok. And is it possible to explicitly read it in my app? Say for example, if I want to display a message like You are in 'x/y' time zone.

Comment: @asanas I would recommend you change your question's title and remove the " in a VueJS app?" as your question is valid in any js app. also it is better to remove the vue tags as well.

Comment: @ImanMahmoudinasab done. thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To get the user's IANA time zone identifier, most modern browsers now support the following:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

That said, the usual reason you would need to use `formatToTimeZone` from [`date-fns-timezone`](https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone) is when you need to use a different time zone other than the user's local zone.  Otherwise, you can usually just use the `format` function from [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/).

However, in your case, you are also trying to use the `z` format specifier to display the user's time zone abbreviation.  This isn't provided by date-fns directly, so if that is critical then you will indeed need to get the user's time zone with the Intl api shown above and use `formatToTimeZone`.

Do keep in mind though that these abbreviations are whatever the IANA data has recorded, which are in English only, and it doesn't have abbreviations for every time zone.  For those that don't, you will see a numeric value instead, such as `-02`.

Also, many abbreviations can be ambiguous (such as the `I` in `IST` possibly meaning India, Israel, or Ireland, and many others...).  Thus, in most cases, if you don't need the abbreviation, you're often better off without it.

Comment: how do I display `IST` instead of `GMT+5.30` for Indian timezone?

Answer (score 9):

Just solved a similar problem myself. The trick is to use the `format` function from `date-fns-tz` instead of the one from `date-fns`.

```
import { format } from "date-fns";
console.log(format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z"));
// 2021-11-29 13:55 GMT-8

import { format } from "date-fns-tz";
console.log(format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z"));
// 2021-11-29 13:55 PST
```

See documentation here:
https://date-fns.org/v2.27.0/docs/Time-Zones

Comment: In the first format shouldn't it be a capital `Z`?

Comment: @AlexDev Yeah, the point of my original comment is that if you use the `format` function from `date-fns` is formats lowercase `z` incorrectly as if it were uppercase `Z`. If you use the function from `date-fns-tz` it works as expected.

Comment: For me I got an actual `z` instead of `GMT-8`. Maybe I'm on an older version though.

Comment: Just to note (because I am struggling with this part of it), the locale also plays into what is displayed in the date-fns-tz format function based on the timezone i.e. if you have timezone as Australia/Darwin and the default locale is en-US, it will give you the GMT+X format, but if you include the locale for en-AU, then you will get "ACST"